# CKEditor customize Text change of image dialogue

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have used ckeditor. How to change the text of image properties?

[image: Here is an example]

Comment: @PGCodeRider I have approved your edit, but in the future, please directly remove greetings, signatures, thank-you, help-me and other fluff. See my subsequent edit. Thank you. :)

Comment: you should remove the right part of your picture (the column starting with "Translate") and instead just specify in your question that you are trying to display translations for each and every text visible.